# How can I merge 2 column in python

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose that I have define one 2x2 matrix using numpy:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3]])
```

Now the other 2x1 matrix:

```
array([[3],
       [4]])
```

How can I concatenate these 2 matrix by column, so that it will become:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

And how can I also delete the specify column, so that it will became

```
array([[1],
       [2]])
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a `numpy.concatenate` [method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
import numpy as np
np.concatenate( [ np.array( [ [1,2], [2,3] ] ), np.array( [ [3],[4] ] ) ] , axis = 1)
```

or simply use `hstack` or `vstack`

```
np.hstack( [ np.array( [ [1,2], [2,3] ] ), np.array( [ [3],[4] ] ) ] )
```

These can be also used to remove the column (concatenate two subarrays) - this can be used to remove many columns.

To remove i'th column you can take subarrays to this column, and from the next one, and concatenate them. For example, to remove second column (index `1`):

```
a - np.array( [ [1,2,3], [2,3,4] ] )
a1= a[:,:1]
a2= a[:,2:]
np.hstack([a1,a2])
```

so in general

```
def remove_column( a, i ):
    return np.hstack( [a[:,:i], a[:,(i+1):] ] )
```

and then

```
>>> remove_column(a, 1)
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])
>>> remove_column(a, 0)
array([[2, 3],
       [3, 4]])
```

Actually, as pointed out in the comment - numpy implements its own `delete` method

```
np.delete(a, 1, 1)
```

deleted second column

and deleting multiple ones can be performed using

```
np.delete(a, [column1, columne2, ..., columnK], 1)
```

The third argument is the axis specifier, `0` would imply rows, `1` columns, `None` flatterns the whole array

Comment: it report error :ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: sorry for typo, it should be `axis=1`

Comment: thanks.Now add column using hstack worked.But i still puzzed with remove the specified column,can you give more details

Comment: Why not use `np.delete` to remove columns?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`numpy.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2], [2,3]])
>>> b = np.array([[3], [4]])
>>> np.hstack((a,b))
 array([[1, 2, 3],
        [2, 3, 4]])
```

Removing is even easier, just slice:

```
>>> c = a[:,:1]
 array([[1],
        [2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [3]: x = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3]]
In [4]: y = np.array([[3], [4]])
In [9]: z = np.hstack([x, y])

In [10]: z
Out[10]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])

In [11]: z[:,:1]
array([[1],
       [2]])
```